# RegEx replace a pattern in a string in a range

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Full disclosure: I am somewhat new to VBA and newer still to using regular expressions. I know enough to understand *why* my code does not do everything I want, but not *how* to get it there.

I am attempting to search through all worksheets in a workbook for all phone numbers, and replace them with "**(XXX)XXX-XXXX**".

I've found a few helpful threads and managed to get it working if a phone number is the only value in the cell, but if the phone number is part of a larger string it does not detect it.  Even if it did, I am also unsure of how I would go about retaining the rest of the information originally present in each cell value during the replacement because right now it replaces the entire cell value.

Ideally, I would like to make the replacement text (but not the entire cell) appear **bold** and in red, to call attention to the fact that it has been replaced, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this using RegEx.

Finally, (*and this is where I make it way more complicated...*) is it possible to log the changes in an array to another worksheet?
e.g. "Sheet1; Cell A1 changed from: 'The number is 123-456-7890 for pizza delivery.' to 'The number is (XXX)XXX-XXXX for pizza delivery.'" Obviously the above search would need to be modified to exclude the log worksheet.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim StrPattern As String: StrPattern = "^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$"
Dim StrReplace As String: StrReplace = "(XXX)XXX-XXXX"
Dim RegEx As New RegExp
Dim StrInput As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim CL As Range

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each Rng In WS.UsedRange

        For Each CL In Rng

            StrInput = CL.Value

            With RegEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = StrPattern
            End With

            If RegEx.Test(StrInput) Then
                CL.Value = (RegEx.Replace(StrInput, StrReplace))

            End If

        Next CL

    Next Rng

Next WS
```

Comment: Are you always looking for numbers grouped 3-3-4?

Comment: It might be as simple as removing the ^ at the start and the $ at the end as these indicate the match must start at the first character and end at the last character of the text.

Comment: That worked for making it detect the phone number when the cell also contained other content.  Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to just use `StrPattern = "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"`.

Comment: Is this now solved?

Answer (score 0):

**Essentially yes; SJR's original suggestion to remove the "^" from the start and the "$" from the end worked for identifying the phone numbers regardless of whether the cell contained additional content.**  His follow up suggestion to simplify the pattern did not.

The code still needs bit of work, since the RegEx pattern is attempting to search for phone numbers that might be formatted several different ways, such as with or without the "1" in front.  Right now if a phone number was all that was present in a cell, the result is as expected.  However if there was additional text present in the cell, the spaces before and after the phone number are removed in the result.  i.e.: "The number is(XXX)XXX-XXXXfor pizza delivery."  If I attempt to compensate by adding the spaces to the beginning and end of StrReplace, the spaces show up in the results for cells where the phone number was all that was present.  i.e.: " (XXX)XXX-XXXX "

I *think* I can figure it out with another if statement, but if anyone knows the answer to this problem and my desire to make the result bold I'd love to hear it.

EDIT:

I figured it out and incorporated the bold, red font as well using the following:

```
Dim StrPattern As String: StrPattern = "(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?"
Dim StrReplace As String: StrReplace = "(XXX)XXX-XXXX"
Dim RegEx As New RegExp
Dim StrInput As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim CL As Range
Dim IntStartPos As Integer
Dim IntEndPos As Integer
Dim IntTestPos As Integer
Dim IntTotalLen As Integer

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each Rng In WS.UsedRange

        For Each CL In Rng

            StrInput = CL.Value

            With RegEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = StrPattern
            End With

            If RegEx.Test(StrInput) Then
                CL.Value = (RegEx.Replace(StrInput, StrReplace))
                IntTotalLen = Len(StrReplace)
                IntStartPos = InStr(CL, StrReplace)
                IntTestPos = 0

                Do While IntStartPos > IntTestPos
                    With CL.Characters(IntStartPos, IntTotalLen).Font
                        .FontStyle = "Bold"
                        .ColorIndex = 3
                    End With

                IntEndPos = IntStartPos + IntTotalLen
                IntTestPos = IntTestPos + IntEndPos
                IntStartPos = InStr(IntTestPos, CL, StrReplace, vbTextCompare)
                Loop

            End If

        Next CL

    Next Rng

Next WS
```

Comment: Nevermind. Got it by removing the "\s*" from the beginning and end of the pattern.

Comment: Your previous comment really ought to be part of the accepted answer rather than a comment, if this solved your problem. Please also consider posting the final working code, rather than fragmented bits of the solution here and there. (Yes the reader can fairly easily piece it together himself, but it's just not very reader-friendly this way).

Comment: ^^ I second that. It would help future readers who may have similar problems much more.